# Unusual Decrease in Charging Amps

Tags: charging

I got to know about the [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere&hl=en_IN) app, which basically tells you how much amps does your phone draw while charging. I have noticed that my charger keeps on decreasing from 680 mA to 0 mA in 5 minutes and then my phone does not charge. I assumed that the problem is due to the charger and I replaced 2 chargers but couldn't catch what causes this problem. Can someone tell me is this a problem of my device or inputs in the charger or something else!!

P.S.- I am using properly matched chargers.

Comment: Did you try checking the USB connector? Try cleaning it and see what happens

Comment: The USB connector is fine. When I charge the device using the same USB cable through my laptop, I get a stable current.

Comment: Not sure what wrong with the wall charger may be the current is not strong enough to power your phone. Check your phone specs and the charger too. 680 mA is a bit low. You probably need from 1A > 2.1 A

Comment: I has this problem with my Nexus 6. In my case, it was a faulty USB port (not originally, but at one time it fell perpendicualr on the ground when connected with USB). You can consider having it fixed.

Comment: I identified the problem. All the chargers are good but the problem occurs in the data cable. Now I'm wondering why data cables face such problems. Although the cable is not charging but it is transferring the data.